# How to create global object in VB NET

Tags: vb.net, global

I'm triying to build a language dictionary in VB NET in order to be able to have several languages in the application.

This dictionary has a init method that loads from database the entire dictionary and stores it in memory.

In the rest of the classes of the project, I added the reference and I can use directly the object without create a new instance because their methods are shared.

My question is how i have to load the dictionary content in order that the rest of classes only accessing to Language.GetWord method obtains the properly record of the collection, same way as My.Settings class.

When My.Settings is used from any class the values are loaded. I'm looking for the same effect.

This is the code of the class:

```
Public Class LanguageProvider
    Private Shared CurrentLanguage As Collection

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetWord(ByVal Label As String)
        Get
            Try
                Return CurrentLanguage.Item(Label)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Label
            End Try
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Shared Sub LoadLanguage(ByVal CultureId As Integer)
        Dim SQLController As New SqlDataAccessController
        SQLController.SQLSentence = "SELECT DNF_CULTURE_LANGUAGE_LABELS.LABEL, DNF_CULTURE_LANGUAGE_LABELS.VALUE FROM DNF_CULTURE_LANGUAGE_LABELS WHERE DNF_CULTURE_LANGUAGE_LABELS.CULTUREID = " & CultureId & " ORDER BY LABEL;"

        SQLController.OpenConnection()
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        dr = SQLController.GetData()

        CurrentLanguage = New Collection

        While dr.Read()
            CurrentLanguage.Add(dr.Item("Value"), dr.Item("Label"))
        End While

        dr.Close()
        SQLController.CloseConnection()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Function LoadLanguage must be called when the application loads, in order to access once to database.

After that property GetWord must access to the collection with the words and return the result. The problem is that the instances are not the same and the dictionary is not loaded when a class uses it.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, let me warn about catching all exceptions. It could hide errors you don't want to hide. You should probably use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` to store your dictionary, not a `Collection`. That way you can check if the label exists with the `ContainsKey` method and avoid exception-based control flow. And you should also use the `Using` statement (or `Try-Finally` in older VB.NET versions) to ensure you close your SQL stuffs even if it fails.

Comment: Anton and Martinho are trying to persuade you to revisit some of your older questions and, if anyone has provided a good answer to the question, **accept** it by clicking on the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetWord(ByVal Label As String)
    Get
        Try
            If CurrentLanguage Is Nothing then
                  LoadLanguage(theDefaultCultureIdYouWant)
                  ' Now CurrentLanguage is not Nothing any more,
                  ' so LoadLanguage won't be called again
            end if
            Return CurrentLanguage.Item(Label)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Label
        End Try
    End Get
End Property
```

Of course, you have to provide a value for `theDefaultCultureIdYouWant`, depends on what you want to happen if the user just calls `GetWord` without explicitly mentioning a specific culture.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, the problem is the method LoadLanguage accesses to database and it will supose a high loss of performance. The LoadLanguage method must be called once.

Comment: @Nemesys: the LoadLanguage method will be called once, as long as you don't set CurrentLanguage back to Nothing again.

Comment: @Nemesys: I have added a comment for your better understanding. And if you think my answer is helpful, upvote it and accept it, please.